# How to divide the statement " for some $b,c \in \mathbb R$: $\forall x \in \mathbb R:x^2+bx+c \geq 0$" in to appropriate cases

Tags: logic, polynomials

Assume I know that the following statement is true:

For some  $b,c \in \mathbb R$: $\forall x \in \mathbb R:x^2+bx+c \geq 0 \quad (\dagger_1)$.

Now, suppose I want to show that some claim about these particular $b$ and $c$ is true under all possible conditions described by $(\dagger_1)$. How exactly do I go about dividing $(\dagger_1)$ into the appropriate cases? My guess is as follows:

**Case 1.** $\forall x \in \mathbb R: x^2+bx+c \gt 0$

**Case 2.** $\exists x \in \mathbb R: x^2+bx+c \leq 0$

Note that Case 1 and 2 are just the negations of one another. Now, $(\dagger_1)$ can be applied to Case 2, which will actually 'refine' Case 2 to Case 2' which reads:

**Case 2'.** $\exists x \in \mathbb R: x^2+bx+c = 0$.

Therefore, the only two cases I need to consider are Case 1 and Case 2'. Is this correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  What statement are you trying to prove? If you want your subcases to represent a decomposition of your orginal statement then you need case $2'$ to include $\not \exists x\in \mathbb R:\,x^2+bx+c<0$.  But it's not clear (to me) what the point of this decomposition is.

Comment: Is your first statement the same as "Let $b,c \in \mathbb R$ be such that $\forall x \in \mathbb R:x^2+bx+c \geq 0 \quad (\dagger_1)$, or is it saying that such $b$ and $c$ exist?

Comment: Why not consider the 3 cases where $x^2 + bx + c$ is either greater, equal, or less than $0$?  As you know the case where it is less is impossible that leaves two case greater, and equal.... i.e.  **case 1** $x^2 + bx + c > 0$ (do stuff)  **case 2**: $x^2 + bx + c =0$ (do stuff).  **case 3** $x^2 + bx + c < 0$-- this contradicts $(\dagger_1)$.  That's all.

Comment: @lulu the coefficients I am working with are complicated expressions involving integrals. I simplified them to $b$ and $c$. I just wanted to make sure that I am decomposing the statement correctly, as I think there is a mistake in my text book.

Comment: @Peter could you please explain to me what the distinction between the two is?

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: It is a matter of where you start. Do you begin by saying you have particular values $b$ and $c$ for which the expression works, or do you begin by saying that it is possible to find appropriate $b$ and $c$. To me, beginning "For some" suggests you are saying "There exist", but saying "for these particular" suggests you began by selecting them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two are equivalent. Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive, the limit of your function is $+\infty$ in the positive and negative direction. Hence, if there exists an $x$ for which your $f(x) \le 0$, there must be a $k>x$ where $f(k) = 0$. The opposite direction of the if and only if is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2 and 2' are equivalent, since (under your assumption that $\forall x \in \mathbb R:x^2+bx+c \ge2$)
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R\quad\left(x^2+bx+c\le0\Leftrightarrow x^2+bx+c=0\right).$$